# Rstudio: How can I fit a data set containing negative&non-negatives on a distribution(ex:log-normal)?

Tags: rstudio

So, Im trying to fit a set of data to distributions like log-normal, student-t and normal. I was able to do so with normal using:

```
dist2 <- fitdist(logreturn.GSPC,"norm",method ="mge",gof="AD",discrete=FALSE)
```

But struggling to do so with log-normal as command like:

```
dist1 <- fitdistr(logreturn.GSPC, densfun="log-normal",gof="AD")
```

would produce an error as the data set contain negative values. So the data set I'm dealing with is a price of a stock. So, obviously its natural to obtain negative values when I compute the log return of the price.

### Is there any possible way to solve this issue? I've heard that you can shift those data set into the positive region, which can maintain the statistical properties of the sample, but just not sure how to...

Also,

```
dist4 <- fitdistr(logreturn.SBUX, "t", start=list(m=mean(logreturn.SBUX), s=sd(logreturn.SBUX), df=2))
```

Above command gives me an error:

> In log(s) : NaNs produced

Any suggestion for this as well?

Comment: A lognormal distribution is normally distributed after taking the log. You use it to model the data BEFORE taking the log. But if you already took the log you would then use a normal distribution to model the transformed data (under the assumption that the original data is lognormal)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I have to test whether the data would follow other distributions as well like log-normal and student-t and others... I could just state taking log of lognormal would result in normal distribution, however I want to use some R functions like fitdist to show that...

Comment: My point is that if it's negative because you're taking the log then don't take the log in the first place since the distribution should be fit to the raw data